# create lists that contain the rownumbers for which column i contains the maximum value of that row

Tags: r, dataframe

In a dataframe of 4 columns, I'm looking for an elegant way to get 3 lists that contain the names from column 1 if the maximum of that row in which that name is, is respectively in column 2, 3 or 4.

the first column contains parameter names, 
column 2 a shapiro test outcome on the raw data of parameter x
column 3, shapiro test outcome of log10 transformed data for parameter x
column 4, shapiro test outcome of a custom transformation given by the user for parameter x

if this is the data:

```
          Parameter       xval xlog10val xcustomval
1       FWS.Range 0.62233371 0.9741614  0.9619065
2    FL.Red.Range 0.48195980 0.9855781  0.9643206
3 FL.Orange.Range 0.43338087 0.9727243  0.8239867
4 FL.Yellow.Range 0.53554943 0.9022795  0.9223407
5 FL.Red.Gradient 0.35194524 0.9905047  0.5718224
6       SWS.Range 0.46932823 0.9487955  0.9825318
7      SWS.Length 0.02927791 0.4565962  0.7309313
8 FWS.Fill.factor 0.93764311 0.8039806  0.0000000
9    FL.Red.Total 0.22437754 0.9655873  0.9923307
```

**QUESTION: how to get a list that tells me all parameter names where xlog10val is the highest of the three columns (xval, xlog10val, xcuxtomval)**

*detailed explanation, ignore perhaps. ....*

list 1, the rows where xval is the highest value, should be looking like this: `'FWS.Fill.factor'` since that is the only row where `xval` has the highest score

list 2 is the list of all rows where xlog10val is the maximum value, and thus should contain the names of parameters where xlog10val is the maximum of that row:

```
'FWS.Range', 'FL.Red.Range', 'FL.Orange.Range', 
'FL.Red.Gradient', 'FWS.Fill.factor'
```

and list 3 the rest of the names

I tried something like

```
df$Parameter[which(df$xval == max(df[ ,2:4]))]
```

but this gives `integer(0)` results.

**EDIT**

to clarify: 
Lets start with looking at column 2 (xval). 
PER row I need to test whether xval is the maximum of the 3 columns; xval, xlog10val, xcustomval
if this is the case, add the parameter in THAT row to the list of xval_is_the_max_of_3_columns list

Then we do the same PER row for xlog10val. IF xlog10val in row i is max of columns 2:4, add the name of that ROW to xlog10val_is_the_max_of_3_columns list.

To make the DF:

```
df <- data.frame(Parameter = c('FWS.Range', 'FL.Red.Range', 'FL.Orange.Range', 'FL.Yellow.Range', 'FL.Red.Gradient','SWS.Range','SWS.Length','FWS.Fill.factor','FL.Red.Total'),
        xval = c(0.622333705577588,0.481959800402278,0.433380866119736,0.535549430820635,0.351945244290616,0.469328232931424,0.0292779051823701,0.93764311477813,0.224377540663707),
        xlog10val =  c( 0.974161367853916,0.985578135386898,0.97272429360688,0.902279501804112,0.990504657326703,0.94879549470406,0.45659620937997,0.803980592920426,0.965587334461157),
        xcustomval = c(0.961906534164457,0.964320569400919,0.823986745004031,0.922340716468745,0.571822393107348,0.982531798077881,0.73093132928955,0,0.992330722386105))
```

Comment: `as.character(df[df$xval == max(df$xval), 'Parameter'])` should address your needs (although technically this line will return a charcater vector, not a list). That said, could you possibly elaborate on the reason why the length of lists 2 and 3 is greater than 1? Are you looking for top n values (cause max implies one value)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `max.col` to get the index of the maximum value per each row and with that we subset the 'Parameter'

```
i1 <- max.col(df[-1], 'first')
split(df$Parameter, i1)
```

EDIT: Based on the discussion with @Mark

Comment: hm no, this just gives me one list, and not the correct one:  FL.Red.Range    FL.Red.Range    FL.Red.Range    FL.Orange.Range FL.Red.Range    FL.Orange.Range FL.Orange.Range FWS.Range       FL.Orange.Range Not even sure why some names appear more than ones. 
I need 3 seperate lists.

Comment: @Mark In your code, it is comparing the `df$xval == max(df[ ,2:4])`

Comment: @Mark  Do you need `sapply(df[-1], function(x) df$Parameter[which.max(x)])`

Comment: max.col(df[-1])   assigns correct 1,2,3 to the rows, but from there I need to get to a list of all parameter names that belong to 1, another list that belong to 2, and a final that belong to 3. Your original answer just gives messy list

Comment: df$Parameter[which(max.col(df[-1], 'first') == 1)]
df$Parameter[which(max.col(df[-1], 'first') == 2)]
df$Parameter[which(max.col(df[-1], 'first') == 3)] gives what I need

Comment: @Mark Not sure what you are after `i1 <- max.col(df[-1], 'first'); split(df$Parameter[i1], i1)`

Comment: the split goes wrong I think, it gives repeated names rather than the unique names   FL.Orange.Range FL.Orange.Range FL.Orange.Range FL.Orange.Range

Comment: @Mark  If you need `unique` names, just do `lapply(split(df$Parameter[i1], i1), unique)`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/183908/discussion-between-mark-and-akrun).

Comment: could also do `i1 <- names(df[-1])[max.col(df[-1], 'first')]` if you want the list to be named with the cols.

Comment: @Chris  Yes, it will give the corresponding column names, and you can split by that

Answer (score -1):

I'm not sure exactly how you're selecting the parameters for list two and three, however, you can try something like this as well

```
df$Parameter <- as.character(df$Parameter)

par.xval.max <- df[which.max(df$xval), "Parameter"]
par.col3.gt.max <- df[df$xlog10val > max(df$xval), "Parameter"]
par.rem <- df$Parameter[! df$Parameter %in% c(par.xval.max, par.col3.gt.max)]
```

In this case, the values from column three are greater than the `max(df$xval)`, and the remaining parameters are taken by negative selection using `%in%`

Comment: I'm not looking for the maximum of the xval column. I need to know by row, whether parameter x has the highest normality score (the numbers ) in xval, or in xlog10val or in xcustomval. So if in row n, the max score of the three columns is in column xlog10val, then parameter name in row n goes into the list that will contain all parameter names where that is the case. If in row n, the maximum of the 3 columns is in xval, that parameter name goes in the list of par names where this is the case. If the maximum of the 3 columns for row n is in xcustomval, then the name goes in the 3rd list